# Detects a click outside document

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, meta-tags, onbeforeunload

I am having a problem to detect a click event outside document, for instance in the closing button of the browser without using the onbeforeunload event, because I have a JSP page that is processing something, using meta refresh to give the status of the process evolution.

Since I am using meta refresh I cannot use window.onbeforeunload event to prevent/confirm the user to exit because the meta refresh will fire up the event. Thus, I need to check manually if the mouse will be clicked outside my document.

I can check if the mouse coordinates are outside, thus can´t associate an click event to that in IE8.

```
if (window.event.clientY < 82 && window.onclick)
```

Someone have any idea out achieve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Detecting the close button isn't possible but you can detect if the user is losing focus of the browser by doing:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    alert('lost focus');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Events don't fire outside of the document, including clicks on the window chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to think about what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like a shaky design if you **must** get the close event of the page. Lots of other events will affect you if that is of a concern.

If you have a JSP page producing and showing the status by a meta refresh - what is your problem with the window closing? That should be of your concern, not how to detect a browser close event.